# XnView on Windows 10 fails to open icons

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association, xnview

I set Xnview as th default photo viewer in Windows 10. Unfortunetly, it didn't cover *.ico files (icons.) so I associated .ico files with XnView as seen in the image below.

[image: File Associations applet screenshot]

However, when I double click an ico in Windows XnView start but it shows its default look with no icon. It seems that Windows doesn't start XNView with a parameter pointing to the path to icon files. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you know the parameter it uses, pl post back. A REG file can be created for that configuration.

Comment: XnView needs only path to a file, e.g. xnview.exe d:\icon.ico

Comment: @w32sh How about this reg file?

Comment: I tried XnView Portable (small) and associated .ico files with it using the "Open with" dialog. That worked fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Give this REG file a shot.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ico]
@="xnviewico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xnviewico\shell\open\command]
@="d:\\portable\\xnview.exe \"%1\""

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ico\UserChoice]
```

Update the path for xnview.exe accordingly.

Edit: If the path contains spaces, like "C:\Program Files\XnView\XnView.exe", enclose the (default) within double-quotes.. as in this REG file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.ico]
@="xnviewico"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xnviewico\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\xnview\\xnview.exe\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: It didn't work. I used Right Click Enhancer and it was able to make it work. There was no need to use the last entry of your reg file and the first entry should also have `@="open"`.

Comment: You're wrong. The first entry defines the custom ProgID, in this case xnviewico. And the last entry clears the per-user choice, in case it points to a different ProgID. That said, the REG file works perfectly fine here.

Comment: I could be wrong but your reg file simply doesn't work on my system but if I use this reg file `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xnviewico\shell\open]
@="open"
"Icon"="" [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\xnviewico\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\XnView\\xnview.exe\" \"%1\""` it works fine.

Comment: The "open" label is optional, as the verb itself is named "open" in my REG file. I double-checked it for you, and it certainly works fine here. Not sure why it didn't work for you though. That's strange.